# Ajax callback values not found with upload managed_file field

Tags: ajax

I have a custom module in drupal 8 that has a few sections that utilize Ajax updates. I also have a "managed_file" field (Form API).
The ajax works fine and updates two dependent fields, but the managed_file loses the form_state after I hit the Upload button.
If I only select the drop-down ajax field, then the $form_state['values'] is updated and retains the values for the fields that exist in the form. However, if I select a file to upload and click on the "Upload" button that is generated by the managed_file element, the $form_state['values'] seems to get reset and the only thing that is present there is the ID of the file that got uploaded. Anything else that was in the $form_state['values'] prior to the upload is lost and the drop-down dependency is broken.

I noticed this is very common issue in drupal 8. So please help in this regard.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {



    $instrument_family_options = static::getFirstDropdownOptions();

    if (empty($form_state->getValue('instrument_family_dropdown'))) {
      // Use a default value.
      $selected_family = key($instrument_family_options);
    }
    else {
      // Get the value if it already exists.
      $selected_family = $form_state->getValue('instrument_family_dropdown');
    }

    $form['instrument_family_fieldset'] = [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $this->t('Choose an instrument family'),
    ];
    $form['instrument_family_fieldset']['instrument_family_dropdown'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('Instrument Type'),
      '#options' => $instrument_family_options,
      '#default_value' => $selected_family,
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::instrumentDropdownCallback',
        'wrapper' => 'instrument-fieldset-container',
      ],
    ];
    $form['instrument_family_fieldset']['choose_family'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Choose'),
      '#attributes' => ['class' => ['ajax-hide', 'ajax-example-inline']],
    ];

    $form['instrument_fieldset_container'] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#attributes' => ['id' => 'instrument-fieldset-container'],
    ];
    // Build the instrument field set.
    $form['instrument_fieldset_container']['instrument_fieldset'] = [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $this->t('Choose an instrument'),
    ];
    $form['instrument_fieldset_container']['instrument_fieldset']['instrument_dropdown'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $instrument_family_options[$selected_family] . ' ' . $this->t('Instruments'),
      '#options' => static::getSecondDropdownOptions($selected_family),
      '#default_value' => !empty($form_state->getValue('instrument_dropdown')) ? $form_state->getValue('instrument_dropdown') : '',
    ];



     $form['mainslider_slide_one']['image_dir'] = [
        '#type'                 => 'managed_file',
        '#upload_location'      => 'public://module-images/home-slider-images/',
        '#multiple'             => FALSE,
        '#description'          => t('Allowed extensions: mp4 avi'),
        '#upload_validators'    => [
          'file_validate_extensions'    => array('mp4 avi'),
          'file_validate_size'          => array(25600000)
        ],
        '#title'                => t('Upload an image file for this slide')
    ];

    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
        ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $trigger = (string) $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#value'];
    switch ($trigger) {
      case 'Submit':
        // Submit: We're done.
        $this->messenger()->addMessage($this->t('Your values have been submitted. Instrument family: @family, Instrument: @instrument', [
          '@family' => $form_state->getValue('instrument_family_dropdown'),
          '@instrument' => $form_state->getValue('instrument_dropdown'),
        ]));
        return;
    }

    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }


  public function instrumentDropdownCallback(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['instrument_fieldset_container'];
  }
```

Comment: You told us how you debugged some problem, but you haven't explained what you are trying to do, and what is actually happening. You only told us that how you've debugged whatever it is that isn't happening the way you want. Can you please update your question to give more context?

Comment: Read description above again i have mentioned problem. I have 2 select boxes and second select box populate via ajax callback by selecting a value from first select dropdown. It works great if i have only these two select fieds. But when i add a file upload field and attach a file, value of second select reset and does not found on submit.

Comment: Sorry, I read the description, and there were details that weren't clear to me, so personally I'm not able to help. Hopefully someone else can. Best of luck.